# C++ : Longest Arithmetic Subarray

Tags: c++, arrays

Given an input array, the output must be the length of the longest arithmetic subarray of the given array.

I am getting a different output other than the desired one. I don't understand where I went wrong, I'm still a beginner so please ignore the rookie mistakes and kindly help me out wherever I'm wrong. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int array[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
        cin>>array[i];
    }
    
    int length = 2;
    int cd = array[1] - array[0];
    for(int i=2; i<n; i++){
        if(array[i] - array[i-1] == cd){
            length++;
        }
        else {
            cd = array[i] - array[i-1];
            length=2;
        }
        cout<<length<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you printing the length inside the for loop?

Comment: Also, you should be maintaining the maximum length. You are resetting it every time you reach an else statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a subsequence then what you did would not accomplish that.

[For example:](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-arithmetic-subsequence/)

```
Input: nums = [9,4,7,2,10]
Output: 3
Explanation: 
The longest arithmetic subsequence is [4,7,10].
```

You would require a nested loop structure (a for loop within the for loop you currently have) to accomplish that as you want to check a certain `cd` with the entire array and not just the next element.

If you require to find a subsequence/subarray given that the elements must be adjacent to one another then your program would work correctly.

Also a big error in your code is that you are printing the length inside the for loop. Unsure of whether that was for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you're resetting `length` after every update. You need a variable to store the maximum of every `length`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int maxn = 1e6;
int arr[maxn];

int main ()
{
    int n; cin>>n;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) { cin >> arr[i]; }

    int length = 2;
    int maxLength = 2; //max variable
    int cd = arr[1] - arr[0];
    for(int i=2; i<n; i++){
        if(arr[i] - arr[i-1] == cd) {length++;}
        else {
            cd = arr[i] - arr[i-1];
            length=2;
        }
        //cout<<length<<" "; //remove this
        maxLength = max(maxLength, length); //update maxLength
    }
    cout << maxLength;
}
```

A few more aesthetic notes:

- `array` is a keyword in C++ used to declare [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Although the program may still run, it could create unnecessary confusion.
- `int array[n]` is a VLAs (variable length array). [It's **not** a C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). It may or may not work depends on the compiler.
- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Sreekar If that's the case, can you mark the answer as correct?